# Can't save chkrootkit command output to a file (after defining a new root)

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, root, rootkit

When I'm running chkrootkit on specific dir:

```
sudo chkrootkit -r /vol
```

I get the right output and everything is okay.
But when I'm trying to save the output to a file, like this:

```
sudo chkrootkit -r /vol > /home/ubuntu/test.txt
```

I get this error:

```
unable to open lastlog-file /vol//vol/var/log/lastlog
```

I've tried with other folders- the chkrootkit command ran fine but every time I try to save it to a file it wont work.
Its worth mentioning, `sudo chkrootkit > /home/ubuntu/test.txt` is working fine.
Which means that the problem is just when the root is changed.
the question is, how to save chkrootkit output the a file after changing the root dir.

(I'm using ubuntu 20.04)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone will face this issue- I wrote a little python script that is doing that:

```
import subprocess
command = "sudo chkrootkit -r /vol"
chkrootkit_output = subprocess.getoutput(command)
with open("/home/ubuntu/test.txt",'w') as f:
    f.write(str(chkrootkit_output))
```

not ideal but working...